# The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded error with a CRON job

Tags: zend-framework, pdo, cron, jobs

I'm trying to run a CRON job that accesses my database and does some file transfer. Adapting it from another CRON job that just had a file transfer, I put the command:

```
php -qn -d memory_limit=128M
```

in front of my CRON file.  I remember that I added the memory_limit because I was transferring files but could not remember for the life of me why I had the -qn -d.  Copying the same command to another CRON job that needs to access a database using the Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql, I got the error:

"The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded error "

And, it was only when I used the command

```
php -q
```

that the error went away.  2 questions, then:

1) What is the  difference between "-qn -d memory_limit=128M" and "php -q" with respect to a CRON job?

2) Why do I have the PDO issue when I use the former command and not the latter?

-Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-n` flag means "don't use any php.ini files", so it's not loading any extensions (causing the PDO error). The `-d` flag allows you to set PHP configuration variables, so in your example you're overriding the default memory limit.

Comment: With this in mind can I have my cake and eat it too?  In other words, is there a config option to load the extension as well as override the memory limit?

Comment: Yup, should work, just remove the -n: `-q -d memory_limit=128M`

Comment: OK!  That makes sense.  However, it was my impression from my host (I'm using a shared hosting provider if that makes a difference) that I needed the -n for the CRON job as well, otherwise the memory_limit=128M would be ignored.  If this is true, is there a way to load the extensions as well through the CRON job, or is the -n in fact superfluous?

Comment: You don't need the -n, your memory limit will still be used. I wouldn't call the -n flag superfluous, but its purpose is completely unrelated to the -d flag.